# Protect admin devise route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, admin

I have this in my `routes.rb`

```
devise_for :admins
```

If I put in URL http://localhost/admins/sign_in, I get the sign_in form for admin model.

I have check this for camouflage this form, to:

```
devise_for :admins, :path => "/d7cispx45g"
```

but I still can access through http://localhost/admins/sign_in.

How can I protect this form so that only I know the path to login as administrator?

Comment: You can try to use the `scope` option. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb#L135-137

Comment: Does Works fine :D Thank you very much! You can put your response for validate it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the karma:

You can scope your devise routes with the [`scope`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb#L135-137) option:

```
scope "/d7cispx45g" do
  devise_for :admins
end
```